# Unable to change file attributes (e.g. immutable) on /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns

I noticed that the network manager frequently changed my DNS server, so I wanted to set the immutable bit on the `/etc/resolv.conf` file, which didn't work. I noticed that the `/etc/resolv.conf` file is actually a symbolic link to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`.

Now, `sudo chattr +i /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` results in:

```
chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

From what I can tell, this means that `/run/resolvconf/` doesn't support such attributes. Is that right?

Xubuntu 15.10;

How can I write-protect my `resolv.conf` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/run` is a `tmpfs` (ramdisk) filesystem, and doesn't support extended attributes:

```
% df -T /run
Filesystem     Type  1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs          tmpfs    393016  6416    386600   2% /run
```

On how to avoid `/etc/resolv.conf` being changed by NetworkManager, I found a possible solution at the [Arch Linux forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=413343#p413343).

Create a `resolv.conf` file containing the settings you wish to keep somewhere in your system (say in `/etc/resolv.conf.DNSoverride`) and put this script in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d`:

```
#! /bin/sh
cp -f /etc/resolv.conf.DNSoverride /etc/resolv.conf
```

The script, quoting `man networkmanager`:

> [...] should be a regular executable file owned by root. Furthermore, it must not be writable by group or other, and not setuid. [...]

Quoting `man networkmanager`:

> [...] NetworkManager will execute scripts in the /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d directory or subdirectories in alphabetical order in response to network events. [...]

This means that the script will copy `/etc/resolv.conf.DNSoverride` overwriting `/etc/resolv.conf` each time a network event takes place, overriding possible changes made to `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer addresses some concerns in the [answer by kos](https://askubuntu.com/a/732761/236230).

Because `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symlink, overriding it directly can cause an error when `resolvconf -u` is automatically run.

First, create your replacement `resolv.conf.override` as below. This is intended to replace `resolv.conf`. Match the permissions and owner as below:

```
$ ll /etc/resolv.conf.override
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 172 Jun 26 20:38 resolv.conf.override*
```

Next, create a script such as `20-resolv-conf-override`. Match the permissions and owner as below.

```
$ cd /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d
$ ll 20-resolv-conf-override
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 101 Jun 26 20:45 20-resolv-conf-override*

$ cat 20-resolv-conf-override
#!/bin/sh
cp -f /etc/resolv.conf.override /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

$ sudo ln -f 20-resolv-conf-override ./pre-up.d/
```

Scripts in `dispatcher.d` run when `NetworkManager` is re/started. In contrast, scripts in `dispatcher.d/pre-up.d` effectively run when the system is re/started. Both are needed.